# Installing wine on Solus OS

Tags: software-installation, wine, solus

I tried to install it from Software Center but without result I also type

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds (nothing)
sudo apt-get install wine  (nothing)
```

Please can someone post full command for install Wine

Comment: Solus is not using `apt` or `apt-get`, nor PPAs. (That is for Debian based systems only, like Ubuntu and Ubuntu-based systems). Solus has its own packaging format and repositories, and they include Wine. Look in the Software Center for Wine, including wine 32-bit. Also, Playonlinux is there.

Answer (score 1):

The package installer for Solus is called `eopkg`, so running `add-apt-repository` and `apt-get` (which are for Debian and derivatives) on Solus doesn't make much sense. Try:

```
sudo eopkg install wine
```